# How to refer to this table column by name when sorting?

Tags: excel, vba

The third line errors out with an error 5, invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
tbl.Sort.SortFields.Clear
tbl.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=tbl.Range("Table[Matter ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

I know the problem is `tbl.Range("Table[Matter ID]")` and I've fixed it by using `tbl.Range.Cells(8)` and it works. But *why* doesn't the first work?

I can go `?tbl.Range.Address` and get a valid range address.

I can go `?tbl.Range.Resize(1).Address` and get a valid range address.

The names "Table" and "Matter ID" are correct. One of the advantages of Excel Tables (ListObjects) is that you can refer to columns by name. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Range("Table[Matter ID]") within tbl but there is a Range("Table[Matter ID]") within tbl.parent.

```
Option Explicit

Sub aswqer()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    With tbl
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Parent.Range("table[Matter ID]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Sort.Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

The Range("table[Matter ID]") is a child of the worksheet that the table resides on, not a child of table.

[image]

Comment: I figured my problem was not knowing the Excel object model well enough. Can you suggest a comprehensive reference? I scour MSDN, but while some of its pages are great, some are not. You find a lot of:

`transmogrify - if set to xlYes, the cell will be transmogrified.`
Of course, that doesn't help if what you really want to know is what "transmogrify" means.